# SQL stored procedure - join a software log table with a new task table to create assignments

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures

I am new to joins and feel that it might best suit this need. I have a software log written to a SQL table that I can't modify. I also have a task table that I created so I can assign an administrator the error and that they can investigate it.

I need a way to bring back unique/distinct errors so I initially created a stored procedure to only return distinct errors (with a date range), due to the number of common errors and narrow scope of the investigating:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUniqueValueNames] 
    @StartDate datetime = NULL, 
    @EndDate datetime = NULL
AS
    SELECT 
        ERRORMSG, MAX(ERRORDATE) AS MessageLogDate
    FROM 
        Server.ErrorLog 
    WHERE
        MessageLogDate BETWEEN Coalesce(@StartDate, MessageLogDate) AND Coalesce(@EndDate, MessageLogDate)
    GROUP BY
        ERRORMSG
```

My intent: I would like to join these two tables, keeping the distinct error message functionality and be able to tell if a log entry has a task assigned to it.

I was guessing that I need to join on the error message. I'm copying some of the values over to the task, and the error (distinct) is what's been driving this situation.

```
TaskTable (Database A)  LA.TaskTbl                          
taskID  TaskDescription TaskProcess **ErrorMsg**    Status  ErrorClassification Priority    SafetoRestart   AssignedUser    taskDate


Log Table (Database B)  Server.ErrorLog                             
ID  **ERRORMSG** ERRORDATE  ERRORITEMNAME   FOLIO   OBJECTID    PROCESSNAME PROCID  PROCINSTID  PROCSETID
```

Let me know if anything else is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: What exactly is your question & where are you stuck in writing code? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a stored procedure, you'll want to use a **table-valued function**. Syntax varies a bit between DBMSs (it helps to tag queries with the DBMS you are using), but the advantage of table-valued functions is that they can be used in queries like regular tables:

```
SELECT log.*, task.* -- or whatever you are interested in
FROM LogTable log
JOIN GetUniqueValueNames(...) errors ON errors.ErrorMsg = log.ErrorMsg
LEFT OUTER JOIN TaskTable task ON task.ErrorMsg = log.ErrorMsg
```

or slightly less efficient by more readable:

```
SELECT log.*, task.* -- or whatever you are interested in
FROM LogTable log
LEFT OUTER JOIN TaskTable task ON task.ErrorMsg = log.ErrorMsg
WHERE log.ErrorMsg IN (SELECT ErrorMsg from GetUniqueValueNames(...))
```

An advantage of the first query is that you can also select the MessageLogDate.